# How to write a method that accesses the system?

Tags: java, processbuilder

My program is almost working but the second array in my main isn't displaying anything. I can't figure out why. Here is my code.

```
package myutilites;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class extraCredit
{
public static void main(String args [])
{
     ArrayList<String> array = system("ls -l");
     for(String s: array)
        System.out.println(s);

     ArrayList<String> array1 = system("ls -l *.java");
     for(String a: array1)
      System.out.println(a);
}

public static ArrayList<String> system(String string)
    {
            ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> infoArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            String s = string;
            StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(s,"\\,: ");
            while(tok.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                    array.add(tok.nextToken());
            }
            for (String a : array)
                    System.out.println(a);

            try
            {
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(array);
                    Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
                    env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
                    env.remove("OTHERVAR");
                    env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
                    pb.directory();
                    Process p = pb.start();


                    Scanner c = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
                    while(c.hasNext())
                    {
                            infoArray.add(c.nextLine());
                    }
                    c.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {}
            return infoArray;
 }
}
```

my output is this. the ls -l *.java doesn't work.

```
ls
-l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   8 brianhammons  staff  272 Sep 10 09:44 bin
drwxr-xr-x  10 brianhammons  staff  340 Sep  9 10:04 src
ls
-l
*.java
```

Comment: A few general pointers about your code: Try to adhere to Java conventions, that makes code easier to read and understand for others. Classnames should start with an uppercase character, method names are usually better if they contain a verb. The _array_ you are referring to is actually a _list_ (internally backed by an array, hence the name), and it's generally considered good practice to code against an interface `List foos = new ArrayList()`

Comment: OK thanks. I'll remember that next time. Any idea how I get the last arguments to work(ls -l *.java)?

Answer (score 0):

Your input string "ls -l *.java" will not return anything unless you are in the directory containing Java source code. As it is, it is looking for a directory "*.java" which cannot be found. You need to pass in the full path into the system function

Comment: how do i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to do. If you want to find every *.java file on your system then use: "locate *.java".
This will find every instance of a file or directory with "java" in the name icluding source code and system file. Use "locate --help" to find a list of options to use with the locate command.

If you want to find just you source code then you will need to loop through the directory structure looking for your source directories (normally src) and then extract the files.

If you just want to search one specific directory then you must use the command: "cd ". 
EG cd /home/michael/Java.

It would help to learn some basic Bash commands. One of the best sources is http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Main_Page.
If you can be more specific about what you are trying to do I would be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I like using Java to do systems work (I know, it's a bit odd, but that's just me).  However, in your case, I would highly recommend not using it for this task.

Java already has an excellent ability to access the file system details, through the File, Path, and FileSystem interfaces.  Unless you really need something that is truly exotic, you'll get better results through those interfaces than the results you can hand parse and put together yourself.